# Call `getPastEvents` with Drizzle raise error: "getPastEvents is not a function"

Tags: web3js, events, drizzle

Calling `getPastEvents` with Drizzle will cause the exception:

> TypeError: this.drizzle.contracts.Contract.getPastEvents is not a function

How to get all the past events in an array (in-one-shot) when working with Drizzle?

Answer (score 0):

To access `getPastEvents` we need to access the original web3 contract instance ([ref](https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/issues/81)).
This could be achived by using a similar typescript method:

```
  async getPastEvents(event: string = 'allEvents', options: any) {
    const web3 = this.drizzle.web3;
    const contract = this.drizzle.contracts.Registrar;
    const yourContractWeb3 = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, contract.address);

    return await yourContractWeb3.getPastEvents(event, options);
  }
```

To call the above method, use someting like:

```
  const eventOptions = {
    fromBlock: 7228340
    //   toBlock: 'latest'
  };
  const eventsArray = await this.getPastEvents('Registrar', 'BidRevealed', eventOptions);
```